# Creating Canonical URLs including an id and title slug

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-301

I want to replicate what StackOverflow does with its URLs.

For example:

[Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) - ([Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c))

or

[Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/) - ([Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/))

Will Take you to the same page but when they return to the browser the first one is always returned.

How do you implement the change so the larger URL is returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that I've handled this before is to have two routes, registered in this order

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "questions/{id}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Questions", action = "Index" },
    new { id = @"\d+", title = @"[\w\-]*" });

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "questions/{id}",
    new { controller = "Questions", action = "Index" },
    new { id = @"\d+" });
```

now in the controller action,

```
public class QuestionsController 
{
    private readonly IQuestionRepository _questionRepo;

    public QuestionsController(IQuestionRepository questionRepo)
    {
        _questionRepo = questionRepo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
        var question = _questionRepo.Get(id);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title) || title != question.Title.ToSlug())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id, title = question.Title.ToSlug() }).AsMovedPermanently();
        }

        return View(question);
    }
}
```

We'll permanently redirect to the URL that contains the title slug (lowercase title with hyphens as separators) if we only have the id. We also make sure that the title passed is the correct one by checking it against the slugged version of the question title, thereby creating a canonical URL for the question that contains both the id and the correct title slug.

A couple of the helpers used

```
public static class PermanentRedirectionExtensions
{
    public static PermanentRedirectToRouteResult AsMovedPermanently
        (this RedirectToRouteResult redirection)
    {
        return new PermanentRedirectToRouteResult(redirection);
    }
}

public class PermanentRedirectToRouteResult : ActionResult
{
    public RedirectToRouteResult Redirection { get; private set; }
    public PermanentRedirectToRouteResult(RedirectToRouteResult redirection)
    {
        this.Redirection = redirection;
    }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // After setting up a normal redirection, switch it to a 301
        Redirection.ExecuteResult(context);
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static readonly Encoding Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic");

    public static string RemoveAccent(this string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetBytes(value);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }

    public static string ToSlug(this string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var str = value.RemoveAccent().ToLowerInvariant();

        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", "");

        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ").Trim();

        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length <= 200 ? str.Length : 200).Trim();

        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "-");

        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"-+", "-");

        return str;
    }
}
```